# Regex mandatory specific 3 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I have tried this code:

```
/[m,r,k]/
```

I want to check that the string contains all three characters, in this case `m,r,k`. Order is not important.

Comment: can you provide example input?

Comment: @anubhava This would not require each individual letter. `mrk` would pass the test but so would `mrr`, `rrr`, and `m`. This does not ensure the string contains all 3 characters.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood the question. It is always better to add sample inputs for better clarity.

Comment: If you're only using ECMAScript 6-compatible browsers, you could avoid using a regex with something like `var hasAllChars = charsToCheck.split('').every(function(c) { return textToCheck.includes(c) });`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.*m)(?=.*r)(?=.*k).*$
```

[image]

```js
let checkStr = (str) => /^(?=.*m)(?=.*r)(?=.*k).*$/i.test(str)

console.log(checkStr('mrk'))
console.log(checkStr('mr'))
```

Comment: This correctly answers "order is not important". Strings such as `krm` work with this answer.